# openstack installation on multi-node IP address confusion

Tags: mysql, installation, ip, openstack

I am following this guide to install Openstack on a multi node ubuntu vm.
[OpenStack-Icehouse-Installation](https://github.com/ChaimaGhribi/OpenStack-Icehouse-Installation/blob/master/OpenStack-Icehouse-Installation.rst).

It states that :

> Management Network (10.0.0.0/24): A network segment used for administration, not accessible to the public Internet.
>
> VM Traffic Network (10.0.1.0/24): This network is used as internal network for traffic between virtual machines in OpenStack, and between the virtual machines and the network nodes that provide L3 routes out to the public network.
>
> Public Network (192.168.100.0/24): This network is connected to the controller nodes so users can access the OpenStack interfaces, and connected to the network nodes to provide VMs with publicly routable traffic functionality.

I already have 4 VMs with given IP addresses as in:

`10.17.51.53 controller
 10.17.5.82  compute1
 10.17.51.100  compute2
 10.17.51.77  compute3`

In the documentation it says to configure the hosts accordingly:

`vi /etc/hosts
 10.0.0.11       controller
 10.0.0.31       compute1`

As well as in mysql configuration

> Set the bind-address key to the management IP address of the controller node:

`vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
bind-address = 10.0.0.11`

Now, I am confused to as which IP addresses am I supposed to use. The ones that are assigned already to the VMs or i have to assign the IP addresses like 10.0.0.11 to the VM  that acts as the controller which already has ip address 10.17.51.53.

And also, which ip address is to be used for bind-address?

Comment: just saying, OpenStack `icehouse` has been deprecated for a while. You probably want to use a recent version which is either `ocata` or `pike`. A significant difference is that in icehouse, `nova` is still responsible for networking. However, neutron takes over it.

Comment: Right. It has been deprecated, but my VM software is 14.04, so can only install icehouse.

Comment: hmm, i think you can deploy `ocata` with Ubuntu 14.04. Anyways, good luck